# How to use django "site" framework on google app engine

Tags: django, google-app-engine, installation

I'm going to answer my question. I ask this so that other people who is still searching on how to create a django "site" will have a clear answer.

The django documentation had show how to use the django site framework. But strangely, after googling for quite a while, I can't find a good instruction on how to install the site framework. We all know to install an app, we put 'django.contrib.sites' on the INSTALLED_APP list. But how to add the site? Using the admin interface will result in error that say that the site framework is installed but no site is configured (Duhh!). So, we have to assign SITE_ID on the setting.py. But what is the id? From some source, we know that the it has installed a default site by the domain example.com. But still what is the id? setting it to 0 or 1 will also result in error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is....

First, put 'django.contrib.sites' on the installed app list like usual. 
Then run

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

(At you project directory that is). Then, run:

```
python manage.py shell
```

Then, use the following sequence of code:

```
>>>import django.contrib.sites.models as mod
>>>mod.Site.objects.all().count()
```

Make sure it prints out `1`. If it doesn't you probably haven't run `syncdb` properly.

```
>>>msite=mod.Site.objects.all().get()
>>>msite.pk
```

It will print your default site id. SITE_ID (in setting.py.)to the number given. That should do it. At least on development server.

ps: Strangely, mine is 383L. Not 0 or 1. This is probably google app engine with django nonrel specific.

Comment: does anything need to be done on GAE after using this approach?

Answer (score 1):

Just read the link:

http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/djangoappengine

Answer (score 1):

Definitely the best tutorial I have found:

[Flying with Django on GAE](http://f.souza.cc/2010/08/flying-with-django-on-google-app-engine/)

With this I had my site on appspot after about half an hour.